# Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #2 when trim video and add watermark, music background

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm doing cut video into chunks, then join them and add watermark and background music with the command below.

```
"[-y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20200726-WA0154.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/FXMotion/.cache/.watermark/logo_watermark.png, -stream_loop, -1, -i, /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/DripReport_-_Skechers_(Lyrics)(MP3_160K).mp3, -filter_complex, [1:v]scale=640/4:-1[logo1];[0:v]trim=0:2.483,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[0:v]trim=2.483:7.45,setpts=2.0*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];[0:v]trim=7.45:9.933,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];[v1][v2][v3]concat=n=3:v=1[video];[video][logo1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[vw], -map, [vw], -map, 2, -c:v, libx264, -crf, 23, -preset, veryfast, -shortest, /storage/emulated/0/FXMotion/FXMotion-200810e.mp4, -hide_banner]"
```

But when running I get the following error:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20200726-WA0154.mp4':\n  
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp4v
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp4vmp42isom\n  Duration: 00:00:09.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2080 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt470bg/unknown), 640x352, 2078 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:\n      rotate          : 270
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees\nInput #1, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/FXMotion/.cache/.watermark/logo_watermark.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 335x51, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/DripReport_-_Skechers_(Lyrics)(MP3_160K).mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    title           : DripReport - Skechers (Lyrics)
    artist          : DripReport
    album           : DripReport\n  Duration: 00:01:46.06, start: 0.011021, bitrate: 167 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64
    Stream #2:1: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 400x225, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      title           : attached picture
      comment         : Cover (front)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> trim (graph 0)
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> trim (graph 0)
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> trim (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #2:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
  Stream #2:1 -> #0:2 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help\n[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0x6f73832bc0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6f73832c80] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored\n[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6f73833400] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored\n[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6f73833580] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
[libx264 @ 0x6f44476300] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x6f44476300] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x6f44476300] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[graph 2 input from stream 2:1 @ 0x6ed501c380] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
[mp4 @ 0x6ed53b9a00] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2\n[libx264 @ 0x6f445de500] MB rate (33750000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 0x6f445de500] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x6f445de500] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 6.2, 4:4:4, 8-bit\n[libx264 @ 0x6f445de500] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=7 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x6ed53b9a00] Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container\nCould not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --[aac @ 0x6f44478600] Qavg: nan\nConversion failed!",
```

i run ffmpeg on:

{   *Device*
"os_version": "10"
"model": "SM-A217F"
"brand": "samsung"

}

How to fix it?  thank advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio file has two streams: an MP3 stream and a cover art image. By using `-map, 2,`, both streams are mapped. ffmpeg will then convert the cover image to H.264 as well but this is not an acceptable codec for cover art images. Since you presumably don't need the cover art carried over, don't map it. `-map, 2,` should become `-map, 2:a,`